# How to add a value returned from step body to step title?

Tags: playwright

I have this function which retunes a value:

```
  async getLastMessagePreviewText(): Promise<string> {
    const stepBody = async (): Promise<string> => {
      return this.lastMessagePreview().innerText();
    };

    return test.step('Get last message preview text', stepBody);
  }
```

But I want to see returned value in logs like (pseudo-code below):

```
  async getLastMessagePreviewText(): Promise<string> {
    const stepBody = async (): Promise<string> => {
      return this.lastMessagePreview().innerText();
    };

    return test.step(`Get last message preview text '${stepBody.returnedValue}'`, stepBody);
  }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the way to add returned value to test step title.

But it's easy to log it inside:

```
  async getLastMessagePreviewText(): Promise<string> {
    const stepBody = async (): Promise<string> => {
      const innerText = await this.lastMessagePreview().innerText();

      await test.step(`Last message preview text: '${innerText}'`, () => {});

      return this.lastMessagePreview().innerText();
    };

    return test.step('Get last message preview text', stepBody);
  }
```